# Grails GORM find by object property's property

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

I am looking for an easier grails way(if it exists) to achieve below:

My UserIntegration.groovy domain class:

```
class UserIntegration {
 User user
 Integration integration
 // rest of code
}
```

My Integration.groovy domain:

```
class Integration {
 SomeType type
 // rest of code
}
```

My SomeType.groovy domain:

```
class SomeType {
 String name
 // rest of code
}
```

So basically what I need is a way so that I can find a `UserIntegration` which has `Integration` with `type.name = "someTypeName"`

In other words, I am looking for `UserIntegration.findByIntegrationTypeName("someTypeName");`

Obviously such a dynamic finder does not exist, but is there any easier groovier way to do it? I can currently find out all Integration objects with type = "someTypeName" and then use this integration in `findAllByIntegration` but looking for an easier solution if it exists, preferably a dynamic finder.

Comment: Does `UserIntegration.where { integration.type.name == 'someTypeName' }` work?

Comment: @tim_yates yes it works as expected as it was actually by using criterias. Any other way to do it?

Comment: Add a [named query](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/namedQueries.html)?

Comment: @tim_yates I am looking more of a way to add my own dynamic findByIntegrationTypeName to the UserIntegration class. Maybe write a plugin that generalizes this job to any domain class?

Comment: Isn't that what named queries give you?

Comment: @tim_yates named queries would not be as general as compared to a custom dynamic finder added to a domain class via plugin or otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use HQL to do same

```
def list = UserIntegration.executeQuery(from UserIntegration userInt 
                                        inner join fetch userint.integration integration 
                                        inner join fetch integration.type sometype 
                                        where sometype.name =:name,[name:'someTypeName'] )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UserIntegration.createCriteria().list(max:1){
'integration'{
      'type'{
           eq('name',"someTypeName")
       }
    }
}
```

Hope it works